# How to remove additional folder during uninstallation of Debian package?

Tags: debian, apt

How can a file which is created during runtime be marked for removal during the uninstallation of a Debian package?

Comment: Write it to the post-removal script. (I assume the file was created by the post-install script)

Comment: The file ist created by the binary of the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file or folder isn’t inside a user’s home directory, it can be removed in the package’s maintainer scripts (`postrm` would be suitable), preferably only on purge, not “plain” removal.

There is precedent for this, several packages in Debian have post-removal scripts which delete files they create at runtime (not in their post-installation scripts) when they are purged; for example, `alsa-utils` removes its state files, `amavis` removes all its state...